# Loading a local ParcelJS plugin

Tags: javascript, npm, parceljs

I want to create a plugin so that I can raw-load a certain type of file with parcel. Parcel docs states that:

> Publish this package on npm using `parcel-plugin-` or `@your-scope/parcel-plugin-` prefixes, and it will be automatically detected and loaded as described below.
>   ...
>   Any dependencies listed in `package.json` with these prefixes will automatically be loaded during initialization.

Since this is a one-time thing, I don't want to publish the code on npm as a plugin. How do I load my project-local plugin with parcel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I could not find a way to do this in a `parcel` way, I did this in an `npm` way:

I created a folder named `local_modules` (this can be anything you want.) Then created `parcel-plugin-x` inside `local_modules`. Inside that, I created my plugin as usual. I also created a `package.json` specifying the entry point `main`. You can specify the dependencies required for the module just like if this is a separate project (THIS IS!).

```
{
  "name": "parcel-plugin-x",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Parcel plugin x",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

Directory structure:

```
project-folder---local_modules---parcel-plugin-x  
             |---package.json                  |
                                               |---index.js
                                               |---package.json
```

Then I ran `npm i --save-dev .local_modules/parcel-plugin-x` inside the `project-folder`. It adds the line `"parcel-plugin-x": "./local_modules/parcel-plugin-x",` to the root `package.json`. **This is the standard way of loading local modules in npm.** And everytime you make changes to the plugin, you have to run `npm upgrade`. You should also increase the version of your plugin, too. This copies the plugin to `node_modules` and install dependancies.

According to the parceljs docs:

> Any dependencies listed in package.json with these prefixes will
>   automatically be loaded during initialization.

now it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar, but with [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html).

**In plugin folder** (parcel-plugin-x) just run: `npm link`.

**In the project folder** using the plugin:

- Link to parcel-plugin-x: `npm link parcel-plugin-x`
- In `package.json` file, manually add the dependency to `parcel-plugin-x`

`package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "parcel-plugin-x": "^0"
}
```

Each time you make changes to the plugin, you don't have to run `npm upgrade`, but you might have to remove `.cache` folder created by parcel, because parcel will skip processing cached assets.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with the workspaces option in `package.json`: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces

This library seems to be implementing it: https://github.com/astegmaier/stackoverflow-parcel-namer